# Form inheritance. Cannot convert types

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have got class `EmployeeAccountPresenter` which should operate with objects of `EmployeeAccountView` (which is inherited from `Form` class) and `EmployeeBridge` classes.

```
namespace DBEmployee
{
    class EmployeeAccountPresenter
    {
        public EmployeeAccountView form;
        public EmployeeBridge bridge;

        public EmployeeAccountPresenter(EmployeeAccountView _form, EmployeeBridge _bridge)
        {
            this.form = _form;
            this.bridge = _bridge;
        }
    }
}
```

`EmployeeAccountView` class:

```
namespace DBEmployee
{
    class EmployeeAccountView : Form
    {...
```

In my Form1 class i do:

```
namespace DBEmployee
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            EmployeeBridge eb = new EmployeeBridge();
            EmployeeAccountPresenter eap = new EmployeeAccountPresenter(this, eb);
        }

    }
}
```

But i get an error in 'this' parameter that:

> cannot convert from 'DBEmployee.Form1' to
>   'DBEmployee.EmployeeAccountView'

`EmployeeAccountView` class is inherited from `Form` class. Why cannot i convert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to the current object, which is of type `Form1`. `Form1` in turn is a subclass of `Form`.

Nowhere does `EmployeeAccountView` come into play.

I suspect you actually want to define your form like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : EmployeeAccountView
```

Now `this` will be a subtype of `EmployeeAccountView` which can be passed as an argument to `EmployeeAccountPresenter`.